# Python: How to best handle developing a library and an application that uses it simultaneously?

Tags: python, import, module

Example directory structure of current project:

```
myproject/
  |
  +-- mylibrary/
  |     |
  |     +-- __init__.py
  |     |
  |     +-- (code files)
  |
  +-- webapi/
  |     |
  |     +-- __init__.py       <-- contains Flask API code and blueprints, using the mylibrary code
  |     |
  |     +-- object/
  |           |
  |           +-- __init__.py <-- Flask API code for "object"s, imported via blueprints
  |
  +-- cli/
  |     |
  |     +-- __init__.py       <-- argparse, code to use the mylibrary code from the CLI, etc.
  |
  +-- gui_app/
        |
        +-- __init__.py       <-- the start of a GUI application, using the mylibrary code
```

I am the sole developer, and am developing all of the above pieces of the application in parallel.

My questions:

- How can I best handle writing `import` statements in the three projects (`webapi`, `cli` and `gui_app`) to import code from the `mylibrary` module? I see three options:

  - Use PYTHONPATH or `sys.path` to add `..` to the path of each app using the library. This works for the `__init__.py` files, but I'm not sure how to do it from, say, `webapi/object/__init__.py` without basically adding `../..` to `sys.path`. Additionally, this makes the application much harder to later distribute.
  - Restructure the application so that each "user" of the library is a submodule of the library; then I can do `from .. import mylibrary`. This is a bad idea because it basically makes the entire `mylibrary` module "monolithic".
  - Each time I make a chance to `mylibrary`, install it into my `site-packages`. Then just develop the other three applications using `import mylibrary`. This is quite a pain however, since I'm developing all four pieces of the application in parallel.
- I would be planning to distribute `mylibrary` on its own, so it could be installed by e.g. pip. Then, separately, one can install `webapi` or `gui_app`. (Perhaps `cli` could be merged into `mylibrary` so that if it's run as a module it will present the CLI, but still doesn't solve the problem for the other two apps)

This is my first experience writing a code library at the same time as more than one application that will make use of that library. What is the most "Pythonic", or more accurately, safest and least error-prone way to implement this?

Comment: The last option really is the best one—except that you probably want to install it into a virtualenv, not your global site-packages. If you're planning to distribute it via `pip`, you need to make this design work anyway, so why not take advantage of it, rather than doing that _plus_ one of the others?

Comment: Based on your response, I'm wondering if the best solution may be to symlink the `mylibrary` module into a `site-packages` folder using a venv as you suggested. The only problem is that this won't be carried over in a git repository (since the entire venv folder is gitignored). For me as a sole dev, not a big deal as I can just recreate the symlink if ever needed, but if I ever do distribute the sources... I suppose that's what the readme is for, but it'd be nice if it didn't require extra, unusual manual steps.

Comment: Also, the ultimate goal of any solution was to make it so that the packages which use mylibrary as a dependency can simply do `import mylibrary` without any messing around. But I was trying to figure out the best way to do it given that I'm developing the two parts in parallel. Messing with sys.path would need to be undone after the library is "complete" enough to go in the system site-packages. So the symlink method may be the best way, just have to see if there's a way to have the symlink somehow included in the git repo even though the venv folder is gitignored...

Answer (score 4):

I think you’re overcomplicating things.

Your end goal is that the library and application are both distributed separately, to be installed by `pip`. To make that work, they just need to be separate packages that have their own separate `setup.py`, and the application has the library in its ‘requirements.txt`.

And, once you do that, it solves your development issue as well. Create a virtual environment, and just `pip install` the library into that env while working on the app.

There’s no need to manually symlink or copy anything anywhere. Or to write your tests in such a way that they can work with both an installed library and a relative-pathed library. Or anything else. And no messing with `sys.path`; the library is in the venv’s site-packages, which is already in `sys.path`. Making all of this just work is the whole point of virtual environments.

You don’t even need anything complicated in the readme. People just installing the app with pip (whether systemwide or in a venv) will get the library automatically. People working in the app can treat the library the same way they treat any other dependency. (They should already know how to create a venv and install requirements.txt into it.) The only real issue would be people working on the library who aren’t interested in the app but are using it as test code for the library—but you can just make that unnecessary by including sufficient test code with the library itself (which you probably want to do anyway).

If there’s a reason this won’t work for you, you can look at building a versioned subpackage out of the independent library package, the way `requests` does with `urllib3` or `bs4` does with `unicodedamnit`. But from your description, I don’t see any indication that you need that.

---

I think your problem may be that you think `pip` can only install distributed packages off PyPI or another `pip` repo. In fact, it's a lot more flexible than that. As [the User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages) says:

> `pip` supports installing from PyPI, version control, local projects, and directly from distribution files.

If you look at the reference for [`pip install`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pip-install), it can take any of these forms:

```
pip [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip [options] <archive url/path> ...
```

If you're wondering how this works, oversimplifying a bit, all of the variations (unless you're dealing with prebuilt wheels, which isn't relevant here) come down to (only slightly oversimplified) getting the source downloaded/checked out/unpacked/etc. somewhere and doing a `pip install .`, `cd`ing into that somewhere, and doing a `pip install .` there.

So, if you want to install your library's current working tree, you can just do this:

```
pip install /path/to/lib
```

Or, more often, you're going to already be in `/path/to/lib`, so:

```
pip install .
```

You may want to throw in the `-e` flag for dev-mode installs, or override the version checking (or just `--force-reinstall`), or specify a fake (monotonically increasing) version number with `#egg`, or ignore the requirements or constraints, or whatever, but all of those options work just as well for installing from a local path (or `git` repo or branch or changelist) as they do for installing from PyPI.

Even for really complicated stuff, `pip` can handle it fine. Want to switch back to what's on `master` to compare how your current changes affect things? `pip install git+file:/path/to/lib@master`. Want to give a custom branch to some guy so he can test against it? Push the branch and he can do `pip install git+https://github.com/fdmillion/liblibrary@someguytest`. You'll probably never need any of this stuff, but almost anything you can imagine that you might need, `pip` already has it.

Comment: The problem is that I am developing BOTH the library AND the application at the same time. I'm not working with the typical scenario (a completed library which I am now writing an application against). So during development, I will shift focus back and forth a lot. Today, I might be working on adding some functions to the application, and just put some stubs in the library so it can work without crashing; tomorrow, I'll add some code to the library, but then have to make a change to the application to support it. (This happens when you're the sole developer)

Comment: Therefore, I need to symlink or manually copy over the library code every time I change it, so that the application code can import the current working version of the library.

Comment: @fdmillion No, you just need to `pip install` the library every time you switch back to working on the app, so the current working version gets installed into the venv so the application can import it. There’s nothing stopping you from updating the venv once/day, or even a dozen times/day.

Comment: @fdmillion The only case that can be a bit of a pain is if you’re switching back and forth between conflicting git branches rapidly. For that case, you might want something extra. But just a git hook that uninstalls (or even force-reinstalls) the library on checkout (maybe also testing that you’re in a venv and raising an error if not) solves that.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to figure out how to get the `pip` in the virtualenv to pull in the working tree for the library? (Obviously the library isn't going to be in any sort of published state while it's being worked on). I am thinking I could even include this step in a task runner of some kind, so that each time I launch the apps, the current library is always pulled in?

Comment: @fdmillion if the two packages are in the same repo (or if they’re separate but the library is submoduled into the app), all you need to do is `pip install .` from inside the library’s top-level directory. That will install the current working code of the library into site-packages (of the venv).